# Generate sitemap in Google

Tags: html, jsf

I have website in JSF. When I type the name of the site on Google I want top see website map like this:

[image]

How I can do this in JSF?

Comment: You mean how can I do this in html? If you can do that, it is easily transferable to jsf

Comment: this has nothing to do with JSF. and these "subLinks" or as google called it "sitelinks" are auto generated by google. read more about it here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en

Comment: I created sitemap but still I don't see sublinks on Google